# Is there a way to customize taskbar icons to have this Windows 11 taskbar effect when opened?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, windows-11

I really like the new taskbar line/dots (whatever they are called) in Win 11 when an app is opened. Like this: [image]
Is there a way to customize and get this effect in Win 10?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 underlines Active Icons on the Task Bar. This is default behavior, and you would need a custom third party theme to remove the underline (basic research about this feature).

Accordingly, Windows 10 and Windows 11 are the same in this regard assuming native setup.

Follow up:  Build 22000.120 is out tonight (Aug 5) and all is still the same between Windows 10 and Windows 11 with respect to underlining active task bar icons.